# Windows 10 update error 0x800F0922 - Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1703 for x64-based Systems (KB4516059)

Tags: windows, partitioning, updates

I have a problem with installing this particular update.

I've read that it might need more space in the "System Reserved" partition that windows creates upon installation but for me there was none(!). I don't recall why or how this was done but that's the situation at the moment. To fix that i created a 600mb partition without letter and just marked it 'Active'.

[image]

I don't really think that my Windows installation understands that as the proper partition though... and I think that this should be the actual problem. I also tried running various commands that i found here and there (mostly from this [resource](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/0x800f0922-windows-10.html)) about this specific problem with no avail.

This is the event viewer log

```xml
----------


- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient" Guid="{945A8954-C147-4ACD-923F-40C45405A658}" /> 
  <EventID>20</EventID> 
  <Version>1</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>1</Task> 
  <Opcode>13</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000028</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-30T12:21:15.187310000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>27583</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="3720" ThreadID="7124" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-IPUVSTA</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="errorCode">0x800f0922</Data> 
  <Data Name="updateTitle">2019-09 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1703 for x64-based Systems (KB4516059)</Data> 
  <Data Name="updateGuid">{4BCC4FEC-D215-490B-A075-4C639600C03E}</Data> 
  <Data Name="updateRevisionNumber">201</Data> 
  <Data Name="serviceGuid">{7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D}</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

and another concerning the .NET framework right above

```xml
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient" Guid="{945A8954-C147-4ACD-923F-40C45405A658}" /> 
  <EventID>20</EventID> 
  <Version>1</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>1</Task> 
  <Opcode>13</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000028</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-30T12:21:15.187312000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>27584</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="3720" ThreadID="7124" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-IPUVSTA</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="errorCode">0x800f0922</Data> 
  <Data Name="updateTitle">Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 for Windows 10 Version 1703 for x64 (KB4486129)</Data> 
  <Data Name="updateGuid">{2E7E5661-F7C8-4A21-A65A-52D0FDF8841A}</Data> 
  <Data Name="updateRevisionNumber">200</Data> 
  <Data Name="serviceGuid">{7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D}</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

So Windows will go on and try to install the updates, and then after reaching something like 96% will undo the installation and restart again.

Comment: V1703 is now out of support and Microsoft is updating to newer versions. You need 30 GB or more of free space to do a feature upgrade.  Go to the Microsoft Media Creation Link  and try running a Repair Install to see if this fixes your issue and updates Windows to V1903.

Comment: ok @John i will try this now, my main hard drive has a lot of space, i hope this helps

Comment: @John - Where exactly did you get the 30 GB figure from?

Comment: Feature updates take between 20 and 30 GB to update and create Windows.old. Taken from many newsletters plus experience

Answer (score 0):

My issue is now resolved, i *think* that what was missing from the puzzle was a simple `chkdsk /f` after creating the 600mb partition.